# Proof verification: Independent events

Tags: probability, independence

The question from tutorial

[image]

My attempt

[image]

Asking for proof verification

Comment: What do You mean exactly with $P(U)$? For example one has $P(U=1)=\frac{1}{36}$ since the outcome  $(1,1)$ is the only that realizes that, but $P(U=6)=\frac{11}{36}$ since the outcomes $(i,6),(6,j)$, $i,j=1,...,6$ realize that. You cleary have $P(U=1\cap V=1)=\frac{1}{36}$, now compute $P(U=1)P(V=1)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $P(U=1)P(V=1)=\frac{1}{36}\,\frac{11}{36}$. Hence $P(U=1)P(V=1) \neq P(U=1 \cap V=1)=\frac{1}{36}$.
Therefore $U$ and $V$ are not independent.

Comment: Exactly! Well done.

Comment: Please type out the relevant parts of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Peter Melech posted in the comments above,
$P(U=1)=\frac{1}{36}$, since there is only one pair when $max(X_1,X_2)=1$ and it is when $X_1=1\; , X_2=1$. 
On the other hand, there are 11 distinct combinations when $min(X_1,X_2)=1$ and it is true when $min(X_1=1,X_2=i)$, $1\leqslant i \leqslant 6$.
Hence $P(U=1,V=1)=\frac{1}{36}\, \frac{11}{36}$,
but $P(U=1 \cap V=1)=\frac{1}{36}$.

Therefore $U$ and $V$ are not independent, as $P(U=1)P(V=1)\neq P(U=1\cap V=1)$.

Comment: +1 @flowian it should be $P(U=1)P(V=1)$ instead of $P(U=1,V=1)$ which would usually be to understood as $P(U=1\cap V=1)$ though